# How do I print different random numbers in for loop?

Tags: python, random

I am trying to generate random "credit card" form. But when I do for loop, then it prints the same random generated "credit card number" everytime.
Example:

Output looks like this:

```
2072 3600 8744 7144
2072 3600 8744 7144
2072 3600 8744 7144
2072 3600 8744 7144
2072 3600 8744 7144
```

And I want every "credit card num" with different numbers in it.

Code:

```
from random import choices
from string import digits


cc_digits = choices(digits, k=16)
cc_number = "".join(cc_digits)
space = " ".join(cc_number[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(cc_number), 4))

for x in range(5):
    print(space)
```

Comment: `for _ in range(5): print(*(f'{i:04d}' for i in choices(range(10000), k=4)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate the CC number once and display it multiple times. Instead, put the CC generator *in* the loop.

```
from random import choices
from string import digits

for _ in range(5):
    cc_digits = choices(digits, k=16)
    cc_number = "".join(cc_digits)
    space = " ".join(cc_number[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(cc_number), 4))
    print(space)
```

Comment: It pains me that you have to be so explicit about something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have put the definition of what you want to print before loop,that means it is static when loop run, so what you need to do is put them inside loop like this.

```
from random import choices
from string import digits



for x in range(5):
    cc_digits = choices(digits, k=16)
    cc_number = "".join(cc_digits)
    space = " ".join(cc_number[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(cc_number), 4))
    print(space)
```